# Need macro code for powerpoint 10 to close a presentation and then open a presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This should be simple, but I am new to this. Need to have a macro code that will close a looping  presentation while it is being shown and then open a new (non looping) presentation. Both are saved in ppsx. I know hyperlinks can be used, but that is not ideal for this viewing situation.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Here is the code.

```
ActivePresentation.Close

Dim FileName

FileName = " C:\Users\Tom\Documents\1st Lutheran\Drive in Worship.ppsx”

Presentations.Open(FileName)
```

Now, I want to know how to create a keyboard shortcut for the macro. Haven't been able to figure this out yet.